# In may app, Can I scan the Eddystone beacon even app is closed/killed by the user?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone

My requirment is that, I want run BLE scanning service to scan Eddystone beacon even my app is in background/forground or terminated/killed by the user. is this possible in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot re-launch an app from a killed state on iOS with Eddystone beacons because these beacons are detected with CoreBluetooth APIs which do not support re-launch from a killed state.

What you can do is use a beacon that transmits *both* Eddystone and iBeacon.  The iBeacon is detectable with CoreLocation APIs,  which offer the unique ability to re-launch an app into the background from a killed state on iBeacon detection.

Once launched into the background by iBeacon., the Eddystone beacon can be detected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David!!. is this possible to CoreLocation APIs will re-launch the app even user did the forceClosed/killed from the menu -> swipe up??

Comment: Absolutely, yes.  Since iOS 7.1.1, CoreLocation will launch an app to the background when a CLBeaconRegion being monitored enters the region.